# Unpredictable segmentation fault while retrieving node from BST

Tags: c++, search, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a small exercise about storing some names and phone numbers in BST. The problem I'm facing is that, when I try to search or delete a node(name as the key) in BST with `_retrieve` function, the code works fine on the first try and the search is successful, but when I try to search with exactly the same name(or other names) again in the second iteration of option loop(or maybe the third iter, that's why I called it unpredictable because it works sometimes), a segmentation fault occurs at the moment entering the second recursion of `_retrieve` function according to the debugger.

I've done some research on this kind of error which normally results from accessing members of struct without checking null pointer, but I did check this at the beginning of the function, so now I try to reach out for some help.

code(the problem occurs in `findPeople` and `delPeople`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "0710891_7_22.h"
using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    string name;
    string phone_num;
} PEOPLE;

char getOption();
void delPeople(BST_TREE* contact);
void findPeople(BST_TREE* contact);
void printContact(BST_TREE* contact);
int comparePpl(void* people1, void* people2){
    PEOPLE p1;
    PEOPLE p2;

    p1 = *(static_cast<PEOPLE*>(people1));
    p2 = *(static_cast<PEOPLE*>(people2));

    if(p1.name.compare(p2.name) > 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(p1.name.compare(p2.name) == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

void processPpl(void *pplPtr){
    PEOPLE person;
    person = *(static_cast<PEOPLE*>(pplPtr));

    cout <<  person.name << "   " << person.phone_num << endl;
}

int main(){
    BST_TREE* contact_tree;
    char option = ' ';

    contact_tree = BST_Create(comparePpl);

    //READ INPUT FILE
    fstream contact_file;
    contact_file.open("EX7_22.txt", ios::in);
    string line;
    while(getline(contact_file, line)){
        PEOPLE* pplPtr;
        pplPtr = new PEOPLE;
        stringstream line_ss(line);
        string sub_str;

        getline(line_ss, sub_str, ' ');
        pplPtr->name = sub_str;

        getline(line_ss, sub_str, ' ');
        pplPtr->phone_num = sub_str;
        BST_Insert(contact_tree, pplPtr);
    }


    //START USER LOOP
    option = getOption();
    while(option != '5'){
        switch (option)
        {
        case '1':
            findPeople(contact_tree);
            break;

        case '2':
            delPeople(contact_tree);
            break;

        option =  getOption();
        }
    } 

    contact_tree = BST_Destroy(contact_tree);
    return 0;
}

char getOption(){
    char option;
    bool error;

    cout << "1.Search 2.Delete 5.Quit" << endl;
    do{
        cout << "Enter the option: ";
        cin >> option;

        if(option == '1' || option == '2')
        {
            error = false;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Invalid Input!!!" << endl;
            error = true;
        }
    }while(error == true);
    
    return option;
}

void findPeople(BST_TREE* contact){
    PEOPLE* pplPtr;
    string name;
    cout << "Please enter name to search: ";
    cin >> name;

    pplPtr = static_cast<PEOPLE*>(BST_Retrieve(contact, &name));

    if(pplPtr){
        cout << pplPtr->name << "   " << pplPtr->phone_num << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Person not found" << endl;
    }
}

void delPeople(BST_TREE* contact){
    string name;
    string *namePtr = &name;

    cout << "Please enter name to delete: ";
    cin >> name;

    PEOPLE* dataPtr = static_cast<PEOPLE*>(BST_Retrieve(contact, namePtr));

    if(!BST_Delete(contact, dataPtr)){
        cout << "Person(" << name << ") not found" << endl;
    }

    printContact(contact);
}

void printContact(BST_TREE* contact){
    cout << "***FRIEND DIRECTORY***" << endl;
    BST_Traverse(contact, processPpl);
    cout << endl;
}
```

, and below are the 2 functions used in the header file

```
void* BST_Retrieve  (BST_TREE* tree, void* keyPtr)
{
//  Statements 
    if (tree->root)
     {
        return _retrieve (tree, keyPtr, tree->root);
        
     } 
    else
        return NULL;
}   // BST_Retrieve
```

```
void* _retrieve (BST_TREE* tree, 
                  void* dataPtr, NODE* root)
{
//  Statements 
    if (root)
        {
         if (tree->compare(dataPtr, root->dataPtr) < 0)
             return _retrieve(tree, dataPtr, root->left);
         else if (tree->compare(dataPtr, root->dataPtr) > 0)
             return _retrieve(tree, dataPtr, root->right);
         else
             // Found equal key 
             return root->dataPtr;
        }  // if root 
    else
        // Data not in tree 
        return NULL;
}   // _retrieve
```

here's the struct definition

```
typedef struct node
    {
     void*        dataPtr;
     struct node* left;
     struct node* right;
    } NODE;

typedef struct
    {
     int   count;
     int  (*compare) (void* argu1, void* argu2);
     NODE*  root;
    } BST_TREE;
```

Below are my input file and header file, so don't scroll down if not necessary

Input file

```
Andrew 0939871236
Ben 0937949608
Devid 0965284847
Danny 0951287564
Jack 0951452308
Jane 0934987654
Jone 0932547637
Ken 0947651268
Nina 0987654321
Tom 0927952019
```

Header file

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//  Structure Declarations 
typedef struct node
    {
     void*        dataPtr;
     struct node* left;
     struct node* right;
    } NODE;

typedef struct
    {
     int   count;
     int  (*compare) (void* argu1, void* argu2);
     NODE*  root;
    } BST_TREE;
    
//  Prototype Declarations 
    BST_TREE* BST_Create (int (*compare) (void* argu1, void* argu2));
    BST_TREE* BST_Destroy (BST_TREE* tree);

    bool  BST_Insert   (BST_TREE* tree, void* dataPtr);
    bool  BST_Delete   (BST_TREE* tree, void* dltKey);
    void* BST_Retrieve (BST_TREE* tree, void* keyPtr);
    void  BST_Traverse (BST_TREE* tree,
                        void (*process)(void* dataPtr));
    static NODE* _insert
                   (BST_TREE* tree, NODE* root,
                    NODE* newPtr); 
    static NODE* _delete
                   (BST_TREE* tree,    NODE* root,
                    void*     dataPtr, bool* success);
    static void* _retrieve
                   (BST_TREE* tree,
                  void* dataPtr, NODE* root);
    static void _traverse 
                   (NODE* root,
                    void (*process) (void* dataPtr));
    static void _destroy (NODE* root);


BST_TREE* BST_Create 
        (int  (*compare) (void* argu1, void* argu2))
{
//  Local Definitions 
    BST_TREE* tree;

//  Statements 
    tree = (BST_TREE*) malloc (sizeof (BST_TREE));
    if (tree)
       {
        tree->root    = NULL;
        tree->count   = 0;
        tree->compare = compare;
       } // if 

    return tree;
}   // BST_Create 

bool BST_Insert (BST_TREE* tree, void* dataPtr)
{
//  Local Definitions 
    NODE* newPtr;

//  Statements 
    newPtr = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if (!newPtr)
       return false;

    newPtr->right   = NULL;
    newPtr->left    = NULL;
    newPtr->dataPtr = dataPtr;
   
    if (tree->count == 0)
        tree->root  =  newPtr;
    else
        _insert(tree, tree->root, newPtr);
        
    (tree->count)++;
    return true;
}  // BST_Insert 


NODE* _insert (BST_TREE* tree, NODE* root, NODE* newPtr)
{
      
//  Statements 
    if (!root)
       // if NULL tree 
       return newPtr;
 
    // Locate null subtree for insertion 
    if (tree->compare(newPtr->dataPtr, 
                      root->dataPtr) < 0)
       {
        root->left = _insert(tree, root->left, newPtr);
        return root; 
       } // new < node 
    else 
       // new data >= root data 
       {
        root->right = _insert(tree, root->right, newPtr);
        return root;
         } // else new data >= root data 
    return root;
}   // _insert 

bool BST_Delete (BST_TREE* tree, void* dltKey)
{
//  Local Definitions 
    bool  success;
    NODE* newRoot;
    
//  Statements 
    newRoot = _delete (tree, tree->root, dltKey, &success);
    if (success)
       {
        tree->root = newRoot;
        (tree->count)--;
        if (tree->count == 0)
            // Tree now empty 
            tree->root = NULL;
       } // if 
    return success;
}  // BST_Delete

NODE*  _delete (BST_TREE* tree,    NODE* root, 
                void*     dataPtr, bool* success)
{
// Local Definitions 
    NODE* dltPtr;
    NODE* exchPtr;
    NODE* newRoot;
    void* holdPtr;

//  Statements 
    if (!root)
       {
        *success = false;
        return NULL;
       } // if 
    
    if (tree->compare(dataPtr, root->dataPtr) < 0)
         root->left  = _delete (tree,    root->left, 
                                dataPtr, success);
    else if (tree->compare(dataPtr, root->dataPtr) > 0)
         root->right = _delete (tree,    root->right, 
                                dataPtr, success);
    else
        // Delete node found--test for leaf node 
        {
         dltPtr = root;
         if (!root->left)
             // No left subtree 
             {
              free (root->dataPtr);       // data memory
              newRoot = root->right;
              free (dltPtr);              // BST Node
              *success = true;
              return newRoot;             // base case 
             } // if true 
         else
             if (!root->right)
                 // Only left subtree 
                 {
                  newRoot = root->left;
                  free (dltPtr);
                  *success = true;
                  return newRoot;         // base case 
                } // if 
             else
                 // Delete Node has two subtrees 
                 {
                  exchPtr = root->left;
                  // Find largest node on left subtree
                  while (exchPtr->right)
                      exchPtr = exchPtr->right;

                  // Exchange Data 
                  holdPtr          = root->dataPtr;
                  root->dataPtr    = exchPtr->dataPtr;
                  exchPtr->dataPtr = holdPtr;
                  root->left       = 
                     _delete (tree,   root->left, 
                              exchPtr->dataPtr, success);
                 } // else 
        } // node found 
    return root; 
}   // _delete 

void* BST_Retrieve  (BST_TREE* tree, void* keyPtr)
{
//  Statements 
    if (tree->root)
     {
        return _retrieve (tree, keyPtr, tree->root);
        
     } 
    else
        return NULL;
}   // BST_Retrieve 

void* _retrieve (BST_TREE* tree, 
                  void* dataPtr, NODE* root)
{
//  Statements 
    if (root)
        {
         if (tree->compare(dataPtr, root->dataPtr) < 0)
             return _retrieve(tree, dataPtr, root->left);
         else if (tree->compare(dataPtr, root->dataPtr) > 0)
             return _retrieve(tree, dataPtr, root->right);
         else
             // Found equal key 
             return root->dataPtr;
        }  // if root 
    else
        // Data not in tree 
        return NULL;
}   // _retrieve 

void BST_Traverse (BST_TREE* tree, 
                   void (*process) (void* dataPtr)) 
{
//  Statements 
    _traverse (tree->root, process);
    return;
}  // end BST_Traverse 

void _traverse (NODE* root, 
                void (*process) (void* dataPtr)) 
{
//  Statements 
if  (root)
    {
     _traverse (root->left, process);
     process   (root->dataPtr);
     _traverse (root->right, process);
    } // if 
return;
}  // _traverse


BST_TREE* BST_Destroy (BST_TREE* tree) 
{
//  Statements 
    if (tree)
        _destroy (tree->root);
        
    // All nodes deleted. Free structure 
    free (tree);
    return NULL;
}   // BST_Destroy 

void _destroy (NODE* root)
{
//  Statements 
    if (root)
       {
        _destroy (root->left);
        free (root->dataPtr);
        _destroy (root->right);
        free (root);
       } // if 
    return;
}   // _destroy
```

Comment: can you reduce your code to a [mcve]? We need not see all your code, only enough to compile it and reproduce your problem. Also input is required

Comment: O.T.: `void*` is very C-ish (and good for any pit-fall to tap in). In C++, we have the nice alternative to use templates instead (as you can see in action in the various standard library containers).

Comment: You declare `BST_Retrieve` to return `void *` when it actually returns a `NODE *`.  But elsewhere you `static_cast` that returned value to a `PEOPLE *` when there is no association between the types `NODE` and `PEOPLE`.  The first thing to do would be to tighten up the type-safety of your code by declaring `BST_Retrieve` and `_retrieve` to return `NODE *` and get rid of any incorrect casts.

Comment: @idclev463035818   sure i can, sir

Comment: @Scheff  thanks for the advice sir, I'll note this and keep improving my c++ skills

Comment: @G.M. Thx for the advice sir, I tried to use `void*` for purpose of ADT, but seems like I should have used templates as @scheff said

Comment: @idclev463035818  I've deleted unnecessary lines in my code and added my input file